# Group Totals from Logs by Month

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a log table that stores media requests by act_datetime, app_id, location_id, media_id and media_type_id. What I want is each resultset row to contain type totals for each month.  For example, log records contain:

[image]

I tried using temp tables to extract records by app_id and grouping by month, but I get multiple rows for each total. I can use sub-queries, but how do I get a total row by type for each month?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Brandon

EDIT

The follow code works combining shared ideas:

[image]

This query takes about 13 seconds parsing about 8.1 million rows.  Is that acceptable? Lastly how do you display date as 2018-1 as one column?  I'm getting errors when converting to string since the date is also used in the group and order by clauses.

I also want to try code construct sum( case when media_type_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end )... to see if get same results and speed.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: You've tagged `mysql` and `sql-server` here, which are you using? Also, could you please post your sample data in a consumable format, with DDL please?

Comment: I'm initially using SQL Server, but will need to make this code work for MySQL later.

Comment: replace image with text please

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** this is SQL Server, and not MySQL:

```
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, act_datetime) AS [Month],
       COUNT(CASE WHEN app_id = 14 AND media_type_id = 1 AND location_id = 1 THEN act_datetime END) AS MP3_Messages_MO,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN app_id = 14 AND media_type_id = 1 AND location_id = 2 THEN act_datetime END) AS MP3_Messages_FL,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN app_id = 14 AND media_type_id = 3 AND location_id = 1 THEN act_datetime END) AS MP3_Messages_MO,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN app_id = 14 AND media_type_id = 3 AND location_id = 2 THEN act_datetime END) AS MP3_Messages_FL,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN app_id = 55 AND media_type_id = 1 THEN act_datetime END) AS MP3_Music,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN app_id = 55 AND media_type_id = 9 THEN act_datetime END) AS ZIP_Music
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH, act_datetime);
```

Note you have included no logic for differing years, data for each Month will do a count irrespective of year.

This is also completely untested, due to lack of consumable data.

Comment: This works if all the data is in the same year. If there is more than one year of data, then all data from any January will collide. Better to group by both month and year, or use DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(col), MONTH(col), 1)... (of course those don't work in MySQL).

Comment: Yes, @AaronBertrand, made that caveat in my comments in the post. Just didn't make the (small) extra effort as we haven't had that consumable data yet. :) Hopefully, however, the OP could work out what to do if they do need to do it by Year and Month.